# how to get data from table 1 and where condition in another table

Tags: sql

select name from `table1` where `id` is equal `(select ids from table2 where sno=1)`

```
Table1 :

Name Null? Type         
---- ----- ------------ 
 ID         NUMBER(38)   
 NAME       VARCHAR2(10) 


 id    name
---- -------
1     viky
2     vivaik
3     sagar
4     john


TABLE2 :

Name Null? Type         
---- ----- ------------ 
ID         VARCHAR2(10)
```

how to get this......
thank you

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow! As you are new here, please take your time to familiarise yourself with the site by taking the [tour], reading up on [ask], going through [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and lastly, understanding how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not cleared but hope it may help you

```
 SELECT T1.ID,T1.NAME FROM TABLE1 T1
 WHERE T1.ID=(SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID=1);
```

Result will be

```
  id    name
  ---- -------
  1     viky
```

Comment: @JeenathKumar Dear you should edit your question with your desired result and motive,because your question is not making any sense that what you want.